# Yii2 глобальный экземпляр класса компонента

Tags: yii2

Есть компонент configstr читает из БД параметры 
прописан в конфиге web.php

```
'configstr' => [ 
    'class' => 'app\components\Configstr',
],
```

как мне создать глобальный экземпляр компонент чо бы каждый раз не вызывать его так:

```
Yii::$app->configstr->second_s
```

в этом случае он переиницируется и опять читает БД, 
если прописать $cls_config=new configstr();
то все нормально один раз загружаются параметры из БД.
Как сделать глобальный экземпляр и где его надо указывать?

Answer (score 0):

Сделай синглтон, который один раз получит данные, сохранит их в статику и не будет каждый раз лезть в БД. Например как вариант:

```
class Cfg
{
private static $_instance = false;

public static function getInstance()
{
    if (false === self::$_instance)
    {
        self::$_instance = self::getCfgParams();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}
private function __clone() {}
private function __construct() {}

private static function getCfgParams()
{
    // тут выборка из БД
    return Model::find()->all();
}
}
```

Comment: Я не много не понял, мне надо сразу записать в статику таблицу из БД, в вашем примере мне для заполнения первоначально какой то метод запустить, а потом уже использовать?

Comment: $cfg = Cfg::getInstance(); в $cfg будет то, что необходимо получить из БД в методе getCfgParams(). При этом Cfg::getInstance() можно вызывать несколько раз, запрос в БД будет только один. Это принцип паттерна singletone.

Comment: спасибо, сегодня попробую

Answer (score 0):

Юзайте `Yii::$app->get('configstr')`

Под капотом Yii2 сложит его в кеш

А инициализацию пропишите в методе `init()` компонента

Попробуйте, думаю, получится

Comment: Дело в том что в инит и происходит заполнение
public function init() {
        parent::init();
        $this->_attributes = ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\configstr::find()->all(), 'name', 'val');
    }
и если я вызываю как указал в вопросе Yii::$app->configstr->second_s
то вызывается инит и опять идет заполнение

Comment: или вы предлагаете другое решение?

Comment: Предлагаю попробовать вместо `Yii::$app->configstr->second_s` вот так `Yii::$app->get('configstr')->second_s` (если second_s аттрибут компонента configstr)) )

Comment: Все равно инициализация идет.
В отладчике еще запрос идет: SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `configstr`
зачем выполняется этот запрос, я его точно не использую, он также для всех таблиц выполняется?

Comment: Да, этот запрос `SHOW FULL COLUMNS` Yii2 делает под капотом.
Если не против, могли бы Вы показать код? Либо я сделаю мини проектик и попробую воспроизвести Вашу проблему?

Comment: Код сюда не влазит в комментарий, подскажите куда или как его вставить?

Comment: Выложить на `GitHub` - самый легкий способ)

Comment: Выложил компонент https://github.com/spopov72/yii2-questions

Comment: Okay, вечерком займусь и проверю свою теорию) будет отдельная ветка